# Got a "nan" value for the DHT22 sensor

Tags: mqtt, nan, esp8266, adafruit

## Got a "nan"  value for the DHT22 sensor

I'm having problems with my Nodemcu Esp8266 and DHT22 sensor, the values ​​delivered after a few days of use appear on the serial monitor as "nan"! Incorrect values ​​also interfere with reading the data on the Adafruit dashboard!

Libraries used:

- Adafruit Unified Sensor
- ArduinoHttpclient
- Ethernet
- WiFi101
- Adafruit IO Arduino and dependencies

```
// Adafruit IO Temp e Hum com Switch 
// Tutorial Link: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-io-basics-temperature-and-humidity

/************************** Configuration ***********************************/

// edit the config.h tab and enter your Adafruit IO credentials
#define IO_USERNAME  "*****"
#define IO_KEY       "*****"
// and any additional configuration needed for WiFi, cellular,
#define WIFI_SSID "*****"
#define WIFI_PASS "*****"
// or ethernet clients.
#include <AdafruitIO.h>
#include <AdafruitIO_WiFi.h>
#include <AdafruitIO_MQTT.h>

#include "config.h"

/************************ Comeca Aqui! *******************************/
//Sensor DHT
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <DHT.h>
#include <DHT_U.h>

// pin connected to DH22 data line
#define DATA_PIN 2//D2


//Esp library
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

// create DHT22 instance
DHT_Unified dht(DATA_PIN, DHT22);

// set up the 'temperature' and 'humidity' feeds
AdafruitIO_Feed *temperature = io.feed("temperature");
AdafruitIO_Feed *humidity = io.feed("humidity");
AdafruitIO_Feed *light = io.feed("lightfeed");

// Define correct feeds relays
AdafruitIO_Feed *pumpfeed = io.feed("pumpfeed"); 
AdafruitIO_Feed *fanfeed = io.feed("fanfeed");
AdafruitIO_Feed *lightfeed = io.feed("lightfeed");

// Define pins relays
 int fanPin = 13; // Pin GPIO13 (D7) controll fanfeed relay
 int pumpPin = 5; // Pin GPIO5 (D1) controll pumpfeed relay
 int lightPin = 15; // Pin GPIO15 (D8) controll pumpfeed relay

void setup() {
  // start the serial connection
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // wait for serial monitor to open
  while(! Serial);

  // connect to WiFi 
  io.connect();
  // Initialize pins as output
  pinMode(pumpPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(fanPin, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(lightPin, OUTPUT);

  // initialize dht22
  dht.begin();

  // connect to io.adafruit.com
  Serial.print("Connectando ao Adafruit IO");
  io.connect();

  // wait for a connection
  while(io.status() < AIO_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }

  // we are connected
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println(io.statusText());

  //--

  // Define the callback functions for the feeds 
  pumpfeed->onMessage(pumpChange);
  fanfeed->onMessage(fanChange);
   lightfeed->onMessage(lightChange);

}

void loop() {

  // io.run(); is required for all sketches.
  // it should always be present at the top of your loop
  // function. it keeps the client connected to
  // io.adafruit.com, and processes any incoming data.
  io.run();

  Serial.println("Condições climáticas:"); //conditions
  sensors_event_t event;
  dht.temperature().getEvent(&event);

  float celsius = event.temperature;
  

  Serial.print("Celsius: ");
  Serial.print(celsius);
  Serial.println("°C");

  // save or celsius to Adafruit IO
  temperature->save(celsius);

  dht.humidity().getEvent(&event);

  Serial.print("Umidade: ");
  Serial.print(event.relative_humidity);
  Serial.println("%");

  // save humidity to Adafruit IO
  humidity->save(event.relative_humidity);

  // wait 5 seconds (5000 milliseconds == 5 seconds)
  delay(5000);

}

// Relays
void pumpChange(AdafruitIO_Data *data) {
  int value = data->toInt();
  //Serial.print("Valor recebido para pumpPin: "); //"value for pumpin"
  Serial.println(value);
  
  if (value == 1) {
    digitalWrite(pumpPin, HIGH);
    Serial.println("Bomba ligada!"); //ON
  } else {
    digitalWrite(pumpPin, LOW);
    Serial.println("Bomba desligada!"); //OFF
  }
}

void fanChange(AdafruitIO_Data *data) {
  int value = data->toInt();
  Serial.println(value);
  //Serial.print("Valor recebido para fanPin: ");
  if (value == 1) {
    digitalWrite(fanPin, HIGH);
    Serial.println("Ventilador ligado!"); //ON
  } else {
    digitalWrite(fanPin, LOW);
    Serial.println("Ventilador desligado!"); //OFF
  }
}

void lightChange(AdafruitIO_Data *data) {
  int value = data->toInt();
  Serial.println(value);
  //Serial.print("Valor recebido para lightPin: ");
  if (value == 1) {
    digitalWrite(lightPin, HIGH);
    Serial.println("Luz ligada!"); //ON
  } else {
    digitalWrite(lightPin, LOW);
    Serial.println("Luz desligada!"); //OFF
  }
}
```

- I tested changing the DHT22 data pin to other available pins that didn't have rst values ​​or anything like that;
- I tried to change the version of the libraries, previous versions;
- I changed the sensor jumper cables;

> Until two days ago the period of this post (06/02/2023), the system worked perfectly! Delivering the correct values!

Comment: Something that works fine for awhile, and then suddenly does not usually indicates a memory leak of some sort.  You might want to add some code to your loop() and reports free memory and see if it steadily gets smaller the longer your code runs.

Comment: Well, since I had an Esp-32 too, I ended up doing some other tests and small changes to my code, and so far it's working perfectly! Thanks a lot for the answer anyway, I'll do the tests with the Esp-8266 and see if I reverse the situation, thus showing the correct values ​​again!